# Validate form when unknown group radio button are checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to know how can I validate a form only if all group radio button are checked.

But this need to be dynamic because I don't know in advance how many group of radio button I would have.

Is it possible to know the number of group in a form?

This need to be working on old browser like IE 8 even 6 if possible

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

you can generate your rules on the fly.
define a validation method and its message,

```
$.validator.addMethod("checkifradiochecked", function(value, element) {
//test expression
},'make sure if you check radio'),


var validator = $('form').data('validator');
validator.settings.rules["radio"] = "checkifradiochecked";
```